# How to solve this for $k_i$?

Tags: analysis

Let $\epsilon >0$ and 
$$
\max_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1}2^{-k_i}\leqslant\epsilon.
$$

How can I solve this for $k_i$?

It's the max that confuses me.

--

$2^{-k_i}\leqslant\epsilon\iff k_i > \frac{\ln(1/\epsilon)}{\ln 2}$

Can I now simply take the max on both sides, getting
$$
\max_{0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1}k_i > \frac{\ln(1/\epsilon)}{\ln 2}?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Note that the function $x \mapsto 2^{-x}$ is monotonically decreasing. Hence we have 
$$ \max_i 2^{-k_i} = 2^{-\min_i k_i}. $$
Now continue as you did.

Comment: Do not understand your answer. Because why do you know that  the $k_i$ are increasing?

Comment: Not the $k_i$ are increasing, the function $x \mapsto 2^{-x}$ is decreasing. That is, if say $k_j$ is the min, i. e. $k_i \ge k_j$ for all $i$, we have that $2^{-k_i} \le 2^{-k_j}$ for all $i$, that is $2^{-k_j}$ is the max. So $2^{-\min_i k_i} = \max_i 2^{-k_i}$.

Comment: So I get $\min_{0\leq i\leq n-1}k_i>\frac{\ln(1/\epsilon)}{\ln 2}$?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$